# Qual a melhor forma de começar a desenvolver uma app mobile

Tags: mobile, app

Boa tarde,

Gostava de saber qual a melhor linguagem para desenvolver uma aplicação para mobile e qual plataforma para começar a desenvolver.

Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 2):

Antes de tudo, depende muito do que você **procura**, não existe a melhor linguagem, e sim a que se adequa mais a sua necessidade atual. Se quiser desenvolver para *multi-plataformas* (Android e iPhone ao mesmo tempo), você conta com as seguinte opções:

- Ionic Framework (JavaScript)
- Phonegap ou *Apache Cordova* (JavaScript)
- Unity (C#)
- React Native (JavaScript)
- Xamarin (C#)
- Flutter (Dart)

Leve em consideração que as plataformas citadas acima muitas vezes ***transpilam*** o código escrito para a linguagem nativa da plataforma, exemplo do React Native no Android(que vai de *JSX* para *Java*), o que muitas vezes ocasiona num código nativo "sujo".
Se preferir programar "nativamente" para Android:

- Java
- Kotlin

(Essas duas opções de linguagens são fortemente tipadas, se forem do seu interesse, tudo bem, caso não, alternativa anterior)

*"Ah mas eu posso passar de Kotlin para JavaScript e transpilar para outras liguagens."*

- Ok, mas ainda sim é focada na *Máquina Virtual **Java***.

E por fim, para dispositivos iOS, você conta com:

- Swift
- Objective-C
- Cocoa Touch